# Can anyone make this a function in python? for me to understand

Tags: python

I'm trying to sort a list of string where it should print all "x" first before printing a b c until z 
This code works but I want it in function style for me to understand it more

```
words.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0] != 'x', x))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This all has to do with two facts.

1. Tuples are sorted by index 0, then by index 1, then by index N.
2. False sorts before True when sorting in ascending (forward) order.

---

```
def sort_x_as_first(words):
    things_to_actually_sort = []
    for word in words:
        if word[0] == 'x':
            things_to_actually_sort.append((False, word))
        else:
            things_to_actually_sort.append((True, word))
    # Our things_to_actually_sort has a bunch of tuples where they are
    # (True, word) if the word does not start with x
    # (False, word) if the word does start with x
    temp_sorted_things = sorted(things_to_actually_sort)
    # When applying the sort, the False go first, then the True values after since tuples sort by index 0 first.  For each group of False (the x's) those are then sorted by word.  Same goes for the group of True values.
    sorted_things = []
    for thing in temp_sorted_things:
        sorted_things.append(thing[1])

    return sorted_things
```